# Operator norm of ABC where B is a PSD matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If B is a PSD matrix, I intuitively think it is true that $\|ABC\| \leq \|B\|\, \|AC\|$, but I can not prove it. Anybody can help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: What does $\|A\|$ mean in this context?  Are we specifically using the operator norm induced by the usual norm on $\Bbb C^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is false.  For a counterexample, consider
$$
A = C = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$

---

The statement will hold in the case where $C = A^T$, assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm induced by the usual (Euclidean) norm on $\Bbb R^n$.  One proof is as follows.

Because $B$ is PSD, there exists an $M$ such that $B = MM^T$.  With that, we have
$$
\|ABC\| = \|(AM)(AM)^T\| = \|AM\|^2 \leq \|A\|^2 \|M\|^2 = \|AA^T\| \cdot \|MM^T\| = \|B\| \cdot \|AC\|
$$

Comment: Thank you! Then what if $A = C^T$? Does it hold now?

Comment: Yes, see my latest edit

Comment: In the future, it would be best if you posted changes like this to your question as a new question, so that the answers given remain valid and complete.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is my first question. I will follow the standard in the future.

Comment: @RunStat You're welcome. If you feel that your question is completely answered, click the $\checkmark$ below the arrows on the left to "accept" an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then $AC = 0$, but $ABC = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, so $\|ABC\| > 0 = \|B\| \|AC\|$.

Comment: Thank you! Then what if $A = C^T$? Does it hold now?